# What does "is...glorified" mean in John 13:31? A.V. "Now is the Son of man glorified"

Tags: word-study

In my thinking about "is... glorified" I have 4 points which are mostly pulling in different directions:

1.Quote from N.I.V. Study Bible [1985 Zondervan] footnote re:v31 "Here the idea of glory includes a reference to Jesus sacrificial death on the cross..".
This makes "is.. glorified" something that is going to happen.

2. The literal section of Interlinear N.T. Jay P. Green puts "Now the Son of man was glorified, and God was glorified in Him".
3. A commentary suggested [I have lost the reference] "He was glorified by His doctrines and miracles".
4. Another version: Now, at this point of time, the Son of man is in the position of having been glorified with the Father in the past in Heaven and this is His guarantee that, despite the cross, the Father will reinstate Him to His glory "at once", the moment He returns to Heaven.

   Which is the best translation and what is the meaning of "is.. glorified"?

Answer (score 2):

It is key that it is the **Son of Man** who is glorified in this passage.  The one who left the [glory he shared with God](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2017%3A1-5&version=ESV) to take on flesh was the **Son of God**.  The one who is exalted and glorified in obedient life, sacrificial atonement, and resurrection according to the determinate counsel and foreknowledge of God is the Son of Man.

> “Men of Israel, hear these words: Jesus of Nazareth, a man attested to
>   you by God with mighty works and wonders and signs that God did
>   through him in your midst, as you yourselves know—  this Jesus,
>   delivered up according to the definite plan and foreknowledge of God,
>   you crucified and killed by the hands of lawless men.  God raised him
>   up, loosing the pangs of death, because it was not possible for him to
>   be held by it.  For David says concerning him,
>
> “‘I saw the Lord always before me,
>       for he is at my right hand that I may not be shaken;  therefore my heart was glad, and my tongue rejoiced;
>       my flesh also will dwell in hope.  For you will not abandon my soul to Hades,
>       or let your Holy One see corruption.  You have made known to me the paths of life;
>       you will make me full of gladness with your presence.’
>
> “Brothers, I may say to you with confidence about the patriarch David
>   that he both died and was buried, and his tomb is with us to this day.
>   Being therefore a prophet, and knowing that God had sworn with an oath
>   to him that he would set one of his descendants on his throne,  he
>   foresaw and spoke about the resurrection of the Christ, that he was
>   not abandoned to Hades, nor did his flesh see corruption.  This Jesus
>   God raised up, and of that we all are witnesses.  Being therefore
>   exalted at the right hand of God, and having received from the Father
>   the promise of the Holy Spirit, he has poured out this that you
>   yourselves are seeing and hearing. - Acts 2:22-33

Comment: One aspect of this question is whether "edoxasthe" an aorist can have a future meaning. Which is suggested in 1.

Comment: The aorist usually implies a past event in the indicative, but it does not assert pastness, and can be used of present or future events.   AIP both times in v.31, AIP once in v.32 and then FIA the last two times in v.32.  I think the conditional conjunction ei (if or since) starting v.32 may provide the connection between the Aorist Indicative Passive and the Future Indicative Active renderings of the verb.

Answer (score 1):

Peace.

The statement of the Son of man and God being glorified is stated **after the leaving of Judas** from the company of Jesus and the apostles who were gathered together for the last supper.

This is a forward-looking statement as we are not to keep company with those who are called “brothers” but are covetous such as Judas.  We must not eat with them as was shown to us by Jesus.

The people of the outside world blaspheme God’s Holy Name when they see covetousness being practiced inside the churches.  ALL nations should be glorifying God through us.

Yet, many are following in the footsteps of Judas and are among us. Covetousness should not be named once among us as becoming saints.

Only when one such as Judas is taken away from our midst can the Son of man be glorified and God glorified in Him.

*> 1 Corinthians 5:11-13 KJV (11)  But now I have written unto you not to

> keep company, if any man that is called a brother be a fornicator, or
>   covetous, or an idolater, or a railer, or a drunkard, or an
>   extortioner; with such an one no not to eat. (12)  For what have I to
>   do to judge them also that are without? do not ye judge them that are
>   within? (13)  But them that are without God judgeth. **Therefore put
>   away from among yourselves that wicked person.***

Only then will the people of the world have no opportunity to blaspheme.  We are members of His body, His flesh and bones (the Son of man) and then they shall see and glorify God.

Those who follow after the way of Judas are prevalent among us and they eat another’s bread for nothing (sop = a crumb, morsel …a mouthful).  The sop was dipped as it was worked for by others (others sweat-of-the-brow worked for bread).

> John 13:26-32 KJV (26)  *J**esus answered, He it is, to whom I shall give
>   a sop, when I have dipped it. And when he had dipped the sop, he gave
>   it to Judas Iscariot, the son of Simon.** (27)  And after the sop Satan
>   entered into him. Then said Jesus unto him, That thou doest, do
>   quickly. (28)  Now no man at the table knew for what intent he spake
>   this unto him. (29)  For some of them thought, because Judas had the
>   bag, that Jesus had said unto him, Buy those things that we have need
>   of against the feast; or, that he should give something to the poor.
>   (30)  He then having received the sop went immediately out: and it was
>   night*.

Again, only AFTER Judas’s going out was the Son of man glorified and God glorified in Him.  NOW, is the Son of man glorified and God is glorified in Him.  The world can then glorify God when a covetous man comes out from our midst..

> (31)  ***Therefore, when he was gone out, Jesus said, Now is the Son of
>   man glorified, and God is glorified in him.*** (32)  If God be glorified
>   in him, God shall also glorify him in himself, and shall straightway
>   glorify him.

A friend in whom we trust…a man of peace supposedly…does eat our bread that we have worked for in our gatherings. Yet, he is really against us as he is preventing the eternal life of Jesus from being made manifest in our mortal bodies by the deceptive handling of the Word of God for our money's sake.

> Psalms 41:9 KJV (9)  ***Yea, mine own familiar friend, in whom I trusted,
>   which did eat of my bread, hath lifted up his heel against me.***

We are to be delivered from these men so that the word of the Lord may have free course and be glorified by those of the world as it is with us.   These men are preaching things that they ought not be for filthy money’s sake.

> 2 Thessalonians 3:1-2 KJV (1)  ***Finally, brethren, pray for us, that
>   the word of the Lord may have free course, and be glorified, even as
>   it is with you:*** (2)  And that we may be delivered from unreasonable
>   and wicked men: for all men have not faith.

We must withdraw ourselves from every brother  that does not work for his own earthly things and eat his own bread.  Many are preaching for money’s sake and not working with their own hands to  support their own earthly necessities.

> 2 Thessalonians 3:6-10 KJV (6)  ***Now we command you, brethren, in the
>   name of our Lord Jesus Christ, that ye withdraw yourselves from every
>   brother that walketh disorderly, and not after the tradition which he
>   received of us.*** (7)  For yourselves know how ye ought to follow us:
>   for we behaved not ourselves disorderly among you;

The apostles of Christ did not eat any man’s bread for nothing but worked with labor and travail night and day so that they would not be chargeable to any.

> (8)  ***Neither did we eat any man's bread for nought; but wrought with
>   labour and travail night and day, that we might not be chargeable to
>   any of you:***

They had power to do eat another's bread but turned down this power to eat from the churches they preached to.  It was their decision not to and now **it is binding on all** of us after them to follow their example….their command to work for our own bread and not preach for money’s sake.

> (9)  ***Not because we have not power, but to make ourselves an ensample
>   unto you to follow us.*** (10)  For even when we were with you, this we
>   commanded you, that if any would not work, neither should he eat.

Again,  those who are following after Judas (those who are called brothers but are covetous) must not be in our company.  We are not to eat with them as a little leaven leavens the whole lump.   We must not sit together with them (which is the “fornication”).

We are members of His body, His flesh and bones and we must not be joined with others who are preaching things that they ought not be in order to get money. We perish along with them in their destruction of the flesh from this earth.  The world sees the covetousness and blasphemes His name when the name of God should be glorified by all nations.

> 1 Corinthians 5:9-13 KJV (9)  I wrote unto you in an epistle not to
>   company with fornicators: (10)  Yet not altogether with the
>   fornicators of this world, or with the covetous, or extortioners, or
>   with idolaters; for then must ye needs go out of the world. (11)  **But
>   now I have written unto you not to keep company, if any man that is
>   called a brother be a fornicator, or covetous, or an idolater, or a
>   railer, or a drunkard, or an extortioner; with such an one no not to
>   eat**. (12)  For what have I to do to judge them also that are without?
>   do not ye judge them that are within? (13)  But them that are without
>   God judgeth. Therefore put away from among yourselves that wicked
>   person.

His house is to be called by ALL NATIONS the “house of prayer” but instead they see a “den of thieves” and blaspheme.  Judas was a thief.

> *Mark 11:15-18 KJV (15)  And they come to Jerusalem: and Jesus went
>   into the temple, and began to cast out them that sold and bought in
>   the temple, and overthrew the tables of the moneychangers, and the
>   seats of them that sold doves; (16)  And would not suffer that any man
>   should carry any vessel through the temple. (17)  And he taught,
>   saying unto them, **Is it not written, My house shall be called of all
>   nations the house of prayer? but ye have made it a den of thieves.**
>   (18)  And the scribes and chief priests heard it, and sought how they
>   might destroy him: for they feared him, because all the people was
>   astonished at his doctrine.*

Only when the many people who follow after Judas departs from our company can then God’s name be glorified among the nations as we then become lights in this dark world.  They will see us and then pray to God as they glorify Him through us.

“Judas” was a thief and does not care for the poor of the world…those on the outside who are spiritually poor and do not know God.

He has the “bag” (glōssokomon).  “Glosso” = tongue, language.  “Komon” from “kosmos” =the world.

Those who follow after Judas have the tongue or language of the world and they bare what was put therein. They put up with what comes out of the mouth of the world.

They put up with the blaspheming by the people of the world who blaspheme God’s name and do not care to change their ways so that the world may glorify God instead.    They are thieves and do not care what the world says about them nor of God’s Holy Name. They instead glory in their shame.

> John 12:4-6 KJV (4)  *Then saith one of his disciples, Judas Iscariot,
>   Simon's son, which should betray him, (5)  Why was not this ointment
>   sold for three hundred pence, and given to the poor? (6)  T**his he
>   said, not that he cared for the poor; but because he was a thief, and
>   had the bag, and bare what was put therein.***

They are being “shamed” by the world for their covetousness that the world sees going on inside the churches where they are making merchandise of the people they are leading astray.

The Father’s house should not be a “house of merchandise” yet we find inside it the “moneychangers” exchanging the glory of God that is due Him from all nations for money’s sake….and they do not care what the world thinks about it when they should be.  Those who are exchanging the glory of God (that is due Him by all nations) for money are leaders as they are "sitting" inside the temple.

> John 2:13-16 KJV (13)  *And the Jews' passover was at hand, and Jesus
>   went up to Jerusalem, (14)  And found in the temple those that sold
>   oxen and sheep and doves, **and the changers of money sitting**:*

The “scourge of small cords” is the public shaming of them by the people of the outside world. The people of the outside world use their tongues (the “small cords) to shame the covetousness men inside the temple.

It is a “scourge” upon the churches of men when we keep those who are called brothers but are covetous among us as the outside world publicly shames what is going on inside.  We must expel the wicked…the covetous…from among us…so that the name of God can be glorified among the nations .

> (15)  ***And when he had made a scourge of small cords,*** he drove them all
>   out of the temple, and the sheep, and the oxen; and poured out the
>   changers' money, and overthrew the tables; (16)  And said unto them
>   that sold doves, Take these things hence; make not my Father's house
>   an house of merchandise.

Ye, they…the enemies of the cross of Christ… glory in their “shame” as they continue to mind earthly things that they are “serving” in the church for.

> Philippians 3:18-19 KJV (18)  *(For many walk, of whom I have told you
>   often, and now tell you even weeping, that they are the enemies of the
>   cross of Christ: (19)  Whose end is destruction, whose God is their
>   belly, **and whose glory is in their shame, who mind earthly things.**)*

They have no understanding that the Lord is to change our humiliated-by-sin bodies to be fashioned like unto His glorious body.  We are to have His heavenly, eternal life in this earth so that the outside world may see and glorify God.

If we keep the “daily” sacrifice of our Lord in our body, then His eternal life shall be made manifest in our mortal body giving us His eternal life.  He is able to subdue all things unto Himself by the “working” of His “daily” sacrifice in our lives.

But the enemies of the cross of Christ are keeping this from being manifest in this earth as they are not looking for this to happen and are leading many astray down the broad way to the destruction of their flesh.

> Philippians 3:20-21 KJV (20)  *For our conversation is in heaven; from
>   whence also we look for the Saviour, the Lord Jesus Christ: (21)  **Who
>   shall change our vile body, that it may be fashioned like unto his
>   glorious body, according to the working** whereby he is able even to
>   subdue all things unto himself.*